# How to show that if S=I+T*T, then S inverse exists?

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

This is from Kreyszig's functional analysis text, chapter 3.9 #8.

S can be easily seen to be linear, so what I need to do is to show it is a bijection and the inverse exists. For injection I got $(I+T^*T)x=(I+T^*T)y$ which gives us $x-y=T^*T(y-x)$. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $H$ stands for a Hilbert space.

If $Sx=0$ the $ \langle Sx, x \rangle=0$. This gives $\|x\|^{2}+ \langle T^{*}Tx, x \rangle=0$ or $\|x\|^{2}+\|Tx\|^{2}=0$. Hence $x=0$. So $S$ is a bijection from $S$ onto its range. If we show that $S(H)$ is closed we can invoke Open Mapping Theorem to show that the inverse is continuous.

Suppose  $Sx_n \to y$. Then $S(x_n-x_m) \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$. Hence $\langle S(x_n-x_m), x_n-x_m \rangle \to 0$. This gives $\|x_n-x_m\|^{2}+\|Tx_n-Tx_m\|^{2} \to 0$. So $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $H$. Let $x$ be its limit. Then $Sx_n \to Sx$ so we get $y=Sx$ and this finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$T^*T$ is selfadjoint and since $(T^*Tx,x)=(Tx,Tx)=||Tx||^2 \ge 0$, the operator $T$ is positive. Hence the spectrum of $T$ is contained in $[0, \infty).$ Thus $-1$ is in the resolvent set of $T$. This shows that $S(H)=H$ and that $S$ has a continuous inverse (Open Mapping theorem).